# SQL to LINQ conversion problems

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a SQL query, which i know works as expected. But i need it to be LINQ which i use to interact with the database. The SQL query is:

```
    SELECT * FROM motorposition, experimentmotor, motors 
WHERE motorposition.motorid = experimentmotor.motorid 
AND experimentmotor.experimentid = 13 
AND motors.id = experimentmotor.motorid
```

I have almost no experience with LINQ. Is it even possible to do this in LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would be something like this:

```
var results = from mp in yourcontext.motorposition 
    join e in yourcontext.experimentmotor on mp.motorid equals e.motorid
    join m in yourcontext.motors on e.motorid equals m.motorid
    where e.experimentid == 13
    select new {mp, e, m};
```